# How do I get the columnMenu to render in every column and filter properly in Kendo React Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I have this Kendo React Grid:

```
<Grid
          data={rows}
          skip={page.skip}
          take={page.take}
          pageable={{
            buttonCount: 10,
            info: true,
            numeric: false,
            pageSizes: [25, 50, 100],
            previousNext: true,
          }}
          sortable={true}
          total={total}
        >
          <Column field="ID" title="ID" filter={"text"} columnMenu={ColumnMenu}/>
          <Column field="Communication Status" title="Communication Status" filter={"text"} columnMenu={ColumnMenu}/>
          <Column field="Last Reading" title="Last Reading" filter={"date"} columnMenu={ColumnMenu}/>
        </Grid>
```

As you can see, I have the `columnMenu` set for every column, but it only appears in the furthest right column, the `Last Reading` column. I want the spots marked in yellow to have filters too.
[image: columnMenu]
My other issue is that the filtering gets stuck and the calendar doesn't render properly.
[image: filter and calendar bugs]
I've been following the documentation [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/filtering/), however my code doesn't render the same.

UPDATE:
I have inspected the grid and found that all of the columnMenus are stacking on top of each other on the right side. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Please see the below screenshot of the styling.
[image: Menu Icon Styling]